# What filters are available?

Tags: filter

The help entry for filter explains what the idea is and gives some examples of filters like `sort` and `indent`, but does not list the possibilities.

How can I find out all the possible filters?

Answer (score 4):

consider every program that reads stdin and writes stdout a filter.
What is available is out of scope of vim. It largely depends on your OS and installation. The sort of the example in the vim-docu is not part of vim.
Besides, it is a bad example, since quite a while vim has inbuild-sort.

sed, perl, python, node, cat, tail, less .... are all valid filters

Comment: Ok, so "filter" just means any shell command that accepts from standard input? If that is true, it is not clear from the help file.

Comment: "filter" is a common term for this kind of programs

Comment: @TylerDurden The Art of Unix Programming has some more detailed description/explanations of "filters" (e.g. [here](http://catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch07s02.html#plumbing) and [here](http://catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch11s06.html#id2957637)). The book is worth reading in its entirety for any programmer, IMHO (not just Unixprogrammers).